# Fastify Schema Not Validating Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, schema, fastify

We are working with Node.js in the backend using `Fastify` as the framework.

We have the schema for satisfy that validates the used input.

Here is the schema, in the schema.ts

```
export const profileSchema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    FirstName: {
      type: 'string',
      pattern: '^([a-zA-z]{2,100})+$'
    },
    LastName: {
      type: 'string', 
      pattern: '^([a-zA-z]{2,100})+$'
    },
    MobilePhone: {
      type: 'string',
      pattern: '[0-9]{10}',
    }
  },
} as const
```

main.ts

```
import { profileSchema } from './schema'
const app = fastify()

app.post(`/createProfile`,
    {
      schema: {
        body: profileSchema,
      }
    },
    createProfile
)
```

It is working, however, when we pass a mobile number as a **Number** instead of a **String**, still it is **working** instead of throwing an **`error`**.

Input

```
{
 "FirstName": "John", 
 "LastName": "Doe",
 "MobilePhone": 9876543210
}
```

Idealy since we are passing mobile number as Number, the schema should validate and throw an error.

Comment: I think you have to set `coerceTypes: false` for Ajv; see the [Validation and Serialization](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Validation-and-Serialization/) section of the documentation, after "Note that Ajv will try to coerce the values to the types specified "

Comment: Tried that, still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `coerceTypes` to false when creating your fastify instance

```
const app = require('fastify')({
    ...  // other settings
    ajv: {
      customOptions: {
        coerceTypes: false,
      }
    }
  })
```

This will disable coerce by default to all routes and all schemas. If you only need to disabled coercion for specific routes or schema, you might to use the `setValidatorCompiler` function

Comment: Thanks, for the solution, I was using ``coerceTypes: false`` but not in the same manner, due to which my schema was not validating properly, using your method, it worked. Thanks again.